# Having trouble locating text within span tags

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm specifically searching for "Leg 0" and the other text below it like BOS and MAD, etc. I've played around with xpath and I seem to find text above this section and text below it but I can never find the "Leg 0" text and that below no matter what I do. I've been trying all morning to figure this out and no dice.

Here is the HTML.

```
   <div>
     <span class="debug-section ng-binding">Leg 0</span>
     <span class="debug-value ng-binding">BOS</span>
     -
     <span class="debug-value ng-binding">MAD</span>
     <span class="debug-value ng-binding">BACAT</span>
     /
     <span class="debug-value ng-binding">BA</span>
     <span class="debug-value ng-scope" ng-if="!leg.excludeDynamic">Dynamic</span>
   </div>
```

Any help is appreciated here, I am beyond frustrated.

Comment: Show us your code and exception log

Comment: I've added more HTML and posted my xpath search string. I no longer get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, provide some info about your code and exception you get as @Anderrson suggested.

And second, you **can't find element based on text within span tags (innerHTML) using cssSelector**, you should use xpath in that case. Or some javascript or jquery, but that would probably be overkill in this case.

Comment: Okay that explains the exception. I'll dig from here and post an update tomorrow.

Comment: Glad to help, but if you add more details we could help you more easily.

Comment: I changed the code to not use cssselector and that fixed the exception. That part is solved. My bigger issue is locating the text but I still can't get it to find the text. I'm using By.className("debug-value") and that completely fails to find anything. I've tried various xpaths and I can't get those to work either.

Comment: Please provide your code, it's really impossible to help you when we have to guess which code you used and which exceptions are you getting.

Comment: an example is shown above. No matter what I try it fails. I've tried every div tag, everthing, dozens of combinations and nothing works.

Comment: Firebug is telling me the xpath is "/html/body/div[2]/main/div/ui-view/ui-view/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/section[1]/div[2]/su-itinerary-summary/div/article/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/span[1]"

Answer (score 0):

The answer my friend is blowing in the wind. Brought up Firefox. Enabled the Firebug plug-in. Click the inspection tool. It highlights the HTML line you click on on the web page. Right click. Choose the Xpath copy to clipboard option.

Walla.